# TypeError: Cannot read property 'case sensitive routing' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, stripe-payments

Using node.js nodemon, express, and lib.

OS: Windows 10 Home x64
Node.JS Version: Lts

What I want to accomplish: ExpressJS port running.
What's going wrong: an internal file, but most of the time its one of my code files going wrong (i dont know yet)

Console error:

```js
C:\Users\Aawesome\Documents\Coding\Stripe App\Stripe-Server>npm start

> stripe-server@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Aawesome\Documents\Coding\Stripe App\Stripe-Server
> node lib/index.js

C:\Users\Aawesome\Documents\Coding\Stripe App\Stripe-Server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:355
    return this.settings[setting];
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'case sensitive routing' of undefined
    at Object.set (C:\Users\Aawesome\Documents\Coding\Stripe App\Stripe-Server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:355:25)    
    at Object.enabled (C:\Users\Aawesome\Documents\Coding\Stripe App\Stripe-Server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:422:23)    at Object.lazyrouter (C:\Users\Aawesome\Documents\Coding\Stripe App\Stripe-Server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:140:27)
    at Object.use (C:\Users\Aawesome\Documents\Coding\Stripe App\Stripe-Server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:214:8)     
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aawesome\Documents\Coding\Stripe App\Stripe-Server\lib\api.js:28:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! stripe-server@1.0.0 start: `node lib/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the stripe-server@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aawesome\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-11T16_57_07_076Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Aawesome\Documents\Coding\Stripe App\Stripe-Server>
```

Directory image:

[(Imugur Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il4Nc.png)

Package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "stripe-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node lib/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon lib/index.js\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "stripe": "^8.43.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to debug using the help of stack track given, probably an error at Stripe-Server\lib\api.js:28:23, so maybe there's the problem you're talking about, can't help without more info on this.

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/3373Mjju

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error indicates that `this.settings` is undefined. Based on the small amount of information provided here, the assumption is that `this.settings` is an object and this TypeError is thrown because you can't "look up" a key of name `'case sensitive routing'` on `undefined`. Make sure `this.settings` is an object with a key `'case sensitive routing'` before line 355.